Prove image of four points of elliptic curve are coplanar
It is an exercise of silverman's arithmetic of elliptic curve.
Let  E / K  be an elliptic curve with Weierstrass coordinate functions  x  and  y .
(a) Show that the map
$\phi: E \longrightarrow \mathbb{P}^{2}, \quad f=\left[1, x, y, x^{2}\right]$
maps  E  isomorphically onto the intersection of two quadric surfaces in $ \mathbb{P}^{3}$ . (A quadric surface in  $\mathbb{P}^{3} $ is the zero set of a homogeneous polynomial of degree two.) In particular, if $ H \subset \mathbb{P}^{3}$  is a hyperplane, then $H \cap \phi(E) $ consists of exactly four points, counted with appropriate multiplicities.
(b) Show that  $\phi(O)=[0,0,0,1] $, and that the hyperplane  $\left\{T_{0}=0\right\}  intersects  \phi(E) $ at the single point $ \phi(O) $ with multiplicity.
(c) Let  P, Q, R, S $\in $E . Prove that  P+Q+R+S=O  if and only if the four points $ \phi(P), \phi(Q), \phi(R), \phi(S)$  are coplanar, i.e., if and only if there is a plane  $H \subset \mathbb{P}^{3}$  such that the intersection $ E \cap H $, counted with appropriate multiplicities, consists of the points  $\phi(P), \phi(Q), \phi(R), \phi(S)$ .
I have tried compute the x coordinate of P+Q+R which equals x coordinate of S.But this doesn't seem to work。

See this answer.
